# regexp that chooses records where at least n of the words in a set appear

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to create a regular expression that chooses records where at least 3 of the words in a set appear in the record. I try the regexp below but they all failed to require three matches:

```
  (apple|orange|gray|hair|hat|head){3} --must have three

  ((apple|orange|gray|hair|hat|head).*){3} --must have three
```

Comment: If it is not clear, I mean distinct matches: i.e. any three distinct elements of the set (apple|orange|gray|hair|hat|head).

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*(apple|orange|gray|hair|hat|head).*){3,}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:.*?(?!.*\1)(apple|orange|gray|hair|hat|head).*?){3,}
```

It will exclude the previous match from the next match. And thus make sure you get 3 different matches.

See on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Qygec4BOgo)

Comment: Ok. You would probably need the PCRE library. http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html to use backreferences and lookaheads.

Comment: doesn't work with back-reference enabled regex either, tried with  System.Text.RegularExpressions (.NET 4)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static boolean isContainSpecialChar(String str){
        String exp="((apple)\\s?\\.?|(orange)\\s?\\.?|(gray)\\s?\\.?|(hair)\\s?\\.?|(hat)\\s?\\.?|(head)\\s?\\.?){3}$";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(exp);
        return p.matcher(str).matches();
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isContainSpecialChar("hair apple hat"));
```

### }

```
output:
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity's sake, if you did have real regex (perl), and since nobody has provided a working example of that yet:

```
 /(apple|orange|additionalTerm).*?\1.*?\1/
```